# Unable to launch online_sync_launch.py from launch file

Tags: ros, ros2

By the link

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GutG9bctkdQqRn_ZdvaHvsNkVSr9KgRQ/view?usp=sharing)

I placed an archive with project. It is a diff.drive robot that can be moved around in Gazebo simulation (using teleop), and as its lidar scans the environment, a "map" is created.

Believe it or not, the project ran fine under ROS2 Foxy. I could start RViz, select "Add - By Topic - Map", and I saw lidar scaned picture.

To run it, I used

```
ros2 launch navigation_bot_05 main_simulation_launch.py world:=src/worlds/maze.sdf  slam:=True
```

Then I switched to Ros2 Galactic.

Now it doesn't work UNLESS I start a separate terminal and run

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_sync_launch.py
```

But I already have it (either online_sync_launch.py or online_sync_launch.py, doesn't mater, neither works) in my launch file - and it doesn't cause any effect.

```
slam_launch_file = os.path.join(slam_toolbox_dir, 'launch', 'online_sync_launch.py')
start_slam_toolbox_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(slam_launch_file),
        launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}.items())
ld.add_action(start_slam_toolbox_cmd)
```

Could you please take a look, and tell me how to revive the thing? Running a second terminal is really inconvenient...

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying you have both Foxy and Galactic installed on the same machine?

Comment: No. I removed Foxy and installed Galactic

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nav2_map_server was dying, and then somehow map was not available. I managed to get map (as in Add - By Topic - Map) back by commenting map saver - not sure how to run it, but at least slam is back:

```
start_slam_toolbox_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(slam_launch_file),
    launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}.items())
    
# start_map_saver_server_cmd = Node(
#         package='nav2_map_server',
#         node_executable='map_saver_server',
#         output='screen',
#         emulate_tty=True,  # https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/188
#         parameters=[configured_params])
```